# Reading .BIN file in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, binary

I created a file in notepad with contents -

**10101011**

I saved it as **binary.bin** with encoding **ANSI**.

I created one VB application to read a byte from this file on button click.

```
    Dim datax() As Byte
    datax = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes("E:/test.bin")
    TextBox1.Text = datax(0)
```

I was expecting **datax** to store the equivalent hex value **AB**. But it stores the value **31**, which is the ASCII HEX code of  **'1'**. TextBox1 displays 49, which is ASCII integer code of **'1'**

Why this happened ? I created bin file in a wrong manner ?

Comment: You saved it as a .BIN file, but that doesn't mean its binary data.  It's just a text file that you named .BIN.  Notepad doesn't create binary data.

Comment: Is there anyway to create binary files with our own binary data in it?

Comment: Have a look at the [**`BinaryWriter` class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Hm so notepad seems wrong way to write a bin file. I coded something to write binary files through VB. And I can read from it from VB as expected :-). But I would like to know if there is some Editor like notepad to write binary file ?

Comment: Check for a hexeditor

Comment: Yes that was exactly what I wanted. Thank you all :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notepad is a text editor. You encoded using the default encoding scheme in notepad. It will treat 1 and 0 only as ASCII characters. As far as your requirement is concerned, what you need is a binary or hex editor. Where you can feed hex data and save as hex file. I find this application simple and useful.

Link:
http://googleweblight.com/i?u=http://www.sierrahelp.com/Utilities/CheatUtilities/HexEdit.html&hl=en-IN